# Read from Array in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string array as shown below:
How do I write each one of them to the console?
Below is the code from my c# program: From the below code I have to write all the cats to the console

```
using (RegistryKey ic = clsidKey.OpenSubKey("Implemented Categories"))
                        {
                            string[] cats = ic.GetSubKeyNames();

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't you just do this?

```
foreach (string cat in cats) {
    Console.WriteLine(cat);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in Linq style

```
Array.ForEach(cats, Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: You can also use Array.ForEach(cats, System.Console.WriteLine); as System.Console.WriteLine meets the Action<string> delegate signature

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach(string cat in cats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even more specifically:

```
foreach(string cat in cats)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(cat);
}
```